# Creating object with Copy Constructor (Simple Rule of Three Class) yields run-time error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, copy-constructor, undefined-behavior, rule-of-three

I have the simple program below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter
{
private:
    size_t m_count;
public:
    Counter() :
        m_count(0)
    {
        std::cout << "defctor" << '\n';
    }
    Counter(size_t count) :
        m_count(count)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor" << '\n';
    }
    ~Counter() {
        std::cout << "dtor" << '\n';
    }
    Counter(const Counter& rhs) :
        m_count{0}
    {
        Counter temp{rhs.m_count};
        std::cout << "cctor" << '\n';
        std::swap(*this, temp);
    }
    Counter& operator=(const Counter& rhs)
    {
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }
        Counter temp{rhs.m_count};
        std::swap(*this, temp);
        std::cout << "caop" << '\n';
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr int getCount() const noexcept {
        return this-> m_count;
    }
};


int main() {
    Counter x{1};
    Counter y;
    Counter z{x}; // this fails
}
```

I've tried to construct a simple rule of three class. I get UB on this line `Counter z{x};` which should be calling the copy constructor. Output:

```
ctor
defctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
cctor
ctor
```

Then it repeats `ctor\ncctor` ...

It's been a while since I worked with C++. I just cannot find the error!

Comment: What do you expect `std::swap(*this, temp);` to do other than copying?

Comment: why do you do Counter z{x}; and not Counter z(x);

Comment: @alon Why not? I've gotten used to brace init as a better way to initialize stuff.

Comment: @alon Cos that's what we do now

Comment: In the copy constructor (and copy assignment operator) is no need to copy the contents into a temporary. You could directly do `this->m_count = rhs.m_count`

Comment: You should almost always use [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::swap` only uses the move assignment operator if you have defined one (the compiler will not define one once you add almost any other special member function). You did not, so it falls back to copy assignment.

But your copy assignment operator is defined in terms of `std::swap`. That's of course an endless recursion: To swap you need to assign, and to assign you need to swap. Eventually you get a stack overflow.

You could just initialize `m_count` directly in the copy constructor (and modify it directly in the copy assignment operator). It looks like you are doing half a copy-and-swap idiom, but I'm not sure what you are really going for here.

And yes, in modern C++ you should also implement the move constructor where appropriate. If done correctly, this would fix the `std::swap` recursion. I suggest you look into some examples of how to implement these special member functions correctly.

Comment: _It looks like you are doing half a copy-and-swap idiom_ Wouldn't it be a nice opportunity to mention "Cargo cult programming"? ;-)

Comment: @Max So you are saying that `std::swap` uses the move assignment operator to `std::move`? Very interesting, I didn't know. Is this equivalent to what cppreference website states, that '`T` must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable and MoveConstructible.' which means that a move constructor and move assignment operator must be defined for class `T`. Am I right? If so, it was such a dire moment for me to skimp on these kinds of things. I considered it "small letters".

Comment: @Nikos Yes, it does. Try writing `std::swap` yourself without using it - you will find it difficult :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof A little strange that [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) website, which I find is often linked upon for copy construction and copy assignment operator implementation details (and I too consulted) didn't mention during the end when it says about "creating an exception safe copy assignment operator" that in order to make proper use of the copy and swap idiom you'd have to also create the move constructor and move assignment operator. How can they miss this!?

Comment: @Nikos Oh, I see where you went wrong. If you want to implement copy-and-swap, then you should swap **each member** with the one from the copy (the page you link does this correctly, your code does not - you should swap `m_count` [which is no better than copying it in the first place]). Don't create a copy of yourself and try to swap with that, that's doesn't work. Also, `std::swap` will (as evidenced here) fall back to copy construction + copy assignment if it has to (but use move operations if available).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should change your copy constructor like this:

```
Counter(const Counter& rhs)
{
    m_count=rhs.m_count;
}
```

It will be enough. The result is:

```
ctor
defctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
Press any key to continue ...
```

Comment: It would be preferable to use the member initializer list here (i.e. `Counter(const Counter& rhs) : m_count(rhs.m_count) {}`.